# Qt + OpenCV play videos with std::thread

Tags: multithreading, qt, opencv

Here is my GUI,
[image]

What I want to do here is to display four different videos together. Users input the path to a specific video file and click open, a new thread should be created to play that video.

I have a slot named startThread(), and a funciton to be called in thread named openCamera();

In mainwindow.hpp, it has

```
public:
    static void openCamera(const std::string& address, QLabel* label);
private slots:
    void startThread();
```

In mainwindow.cpp, it has

```
void MainWindow::startThread() {
    std::string address;
    QLabel* label;
    // Get the input from GUI and assign it to std::string address
    // and find the label corresponding to clicked button.
    // ...
    std::thread t(openCamera, address, label);
}
void MainWindow::openCamera(std::string address, QLabel* label) {
    cv::VideoCapture cap(address);
    cv::Mat frame;
    while (cap.isOpened()) {
        cap >> frame;
        // cv::imwrite("/Users/wking/Desktop/test.jpg", frame); // This function works!
        label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(QImage(frame.data, frame.cols, frame.rows, frame.step, QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped()));
    }
}
```

I'd like to implement this by using std::thread. However, it shows nothing. The program doesn't update label after I clicked the button with correct input. Did I miss anything here? Thanks.

Comment: In Qt you can only access widgets from the main thread.

Comment: What if I want to udpate widgets from an additional thread then? I want to play several videos at the same time. Do you have a better practice of handling thread?

Answer (score 2):

Only main thread (GUI thread) can updates UI.
 I have a similar project. I use QThread and Worker class.
Worker class has a slot to read video file. It will emit a signal if finish reading a frame.
In MainWindow, I create some QThreads, move worker objects to threads.
Connect signal frameFinished of Worker with a funtion to display cv::Mat on a label.

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Worker(QString path, int id);
    ~Worker();

public slots:
    void readVideo(QString path = "");

signals:
    // frame and index of label which frame will be displayed
    void frameFinished(cv::Mat frame, int index);

    void finished(int index);

private:
    QString filepath;
    int index;
};
```

Here is worker.cpp

```
#include "worker.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include <QTime>
Worker::Worker(QString path, int id) : filepath(path), index(id)
{

}

Worker::~Worker()
{
}

void Worker::readVideo(QString path)
{
    if (path.length() > 0)
        filepath = path;

    cv::VideoCapture cap(filepath.toStdString());

    if (! cap.isOpened())
    {
        qDebug() << "Can't open video file " << filepath;
        emit finished(index);
        return;
    }

    cv::Mat frame;
    while (true)
    {
        cap >> frame;
        if (frame.empty())
        {
            frame = cv::Mat(cv::Size(720, 576), CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(192, 0, 0));
            emit frameFinished(frame, index);
            break;
        }


        emit frameFinished(frame.clone(), index);
        QThread::msleep(30);
    }

    emit finished(index);
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include "worker.h"

#define MAX_NUM_CAM 8

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class QThread;
class QLabel;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    void init();

private slots:
    void displayFrame(cv::Mat frame, int index);


private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    int numCams;
    QLabel *labels[MAX_NUM_CAM];
    QThread* threads[MAX_NUM_CAM];
    Worker* workers[MAX_NUM_CAM];
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QGridLayout>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    qRegisterMetaType< cv::Mat >("cv::Mat");

    qDebug() << "Main thread " << QThread::currentThreadId();
    init();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::init()
{
    QGridLayout *grid = new QGridLayout;
    int numCols = 2;

    numCams = 4;

    int row = 0, col = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numCams; i++)
    {
        labels[i] = new QLabel;

        row = i / numCols;
        col = i % numCols;
        grid->addWidget(labels[i], row, col);


        threads[i] = new QThread;
        workers[i] = new Worker(QString("/home/shang/Videos/%1.mp4").arg(i+1), i);
        workers[i]->moveToThread(threads[i]);

        connect(workers[i], SIGNAL(frameFinished(cv::Mat, int)), this, SLOT(displayFrame(cv::Mat,int)));
        connect(threads[i], SIGNAL(started()), workers[i], SLOT(readVideo()));

        connect(workers[i], SIGNAL(finished(int)), threads[i], SLOT(quit()));
        connect(workers[i], SIGNAL(finished(int)), workers[i], SLOT(deleteLater()));

        connect(threads[i], SIGNAL(finished()), threads[i], SLOT(deleteLater()));

        threads[i]->start();
    }

    this->centralWidget()->setLayout(grid);

}

void MainWindow::displayFrame(cv::Mat frame, int index)
{
    QPixmap p = QPixmap::fromImage(QImage(frame.data, frame.cols, frame.rows, frame.step, QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped());
    p = p.scaled(QSize(frame.cols/2, frame.rows/2));
    labels[index]->setPixmap(p);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Qt you can only access widgets from the main thread. You can pass data from your worker threads to the main thread using Qt signal-slot mechanism:

```
class MainWindow
{
    ...

    static void openCamera(const std::string& address, QLabel* label, MainWindow *window);

signals:
    void updateLabelSig(QLabel *label, QPixmap pic);

private slots:
    void updateLabel(QLabel *label, QPixmap pic);

    ...
}

MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(updateLabelSig(QLabel*, QPixmap), this, SLOT(QLabel*, QPixmap));
    ...
}

void MainWindow::startThread() 
{
    std::string address;
    QLabel* label;
    // Get the input from GUI and assign it to std::string address
    // and find the label corresponding to clicked button.
    // ...
    std::thread t(openCamera, address, label, this);
}

void MainWindow::openCamera(std::string address, QLabel* label, MainWindow *window) 
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap(address);
    cv::Mat frame;
    while (cap.isOpened()) {
        cap >> frame;
        // cv::imwrite("/Users/wking/Desktop/test.jpg", frame); // This function works!

        QPixmap pic = QPixmap::fromImage(QImage(frame.data, frame.cols, frame.rows, frame.step, QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped());

        window->updateLabelSig(label, pic);
    }
}

void MainWindow::updateLabel(QLabel *label, QPixmap pic)
{
     label->setPixmap(pic);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.maybe you miss `t.detach();`

2.To update ui:you can emit a signal form sub-thread,then update ui in slot function.(the slot function will run in main thread)