# QT Update variable of worker thread from mainwindow

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, opencv

I am displaying opencv video using QT multithreading concept as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29338250/qt-opencv-play-videos-with-stdthread)

I also wish to update private "path" variable of worker thread class on button click. So I added

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(send_to_worker(QString)),workers[view], SLOT(get_from_main(QString)));
```

However, get_from_main(QString) function never gets called.

May I please know what is the safest method to update worker thread class variable from mainwindow ?

Here is full code..

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Worker(QString path, int id);
    ~Worker();

public slots:
    void readVideo(QString path = "");
    void get_from_main(QString path);

signals:
    // frame and index of label which frame will be displayed
    void frameFinished(cv::Mat frame, int index);

    void finished(int index);

private:
    QString filepath;
    int index;
};

//worker.cpp
#include "worker.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include <QTime>
Worker::Worker(QString path, int id) : filepath(path), index(id)
{

}

Worker::~Worker()
{
}

void Worker::get_from_main(QString path)
{
      qDebug() << "updating";
}

void Worker::readVideo(QString path)
{
    if (path.length() > 0)
        filepath = path;

    cv::VideoCapture cap(filepath.toStdString());

    if (! cap.isOpened())
    {
        qDebug() << "Can't open video file " << filepath;
        emit finished(index);
        return;
    }

    cv::Mat frame;
    while (true)
    {
        cap >> frame;
        if (frame.empty())
        {
            frame = cv::Mat(cv::Size(720, 576), CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(192, 0, 0));
            emit frameFinished(frame, index);
            break;
        }


        emit frameFinished(frame.clone(), index);
        QThread::msleep(30);
    }

    emit finished(index);
}

//mainwindow.h
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include "worker.h"

#define MAX_NUM_CAM 8

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class QThread;
class QLabel;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    void init();

private slots:
    void displayFrame(cv::Mat frame, int index);
    void file_open_clicked();

signals:
send_to_worker(QString path);


private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    int numCams;
    QLabel *labels[MAX_NUM_CAM];
    QThread* threads[MAX_NUM_CAM];
    Worker* workers[MAX_NUM_CAM];
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H


//mainwindow.cpp

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QGridLayout>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    qRegisterMetaType< cv::Mat >("cv::Mat");

    qDebug() << "Main thread " << QThread::currentThreadId();
    init();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::init()
{
    QGridLayout *grid = new QGridLayout;
    int numCols = 2;

    numCams = 4;

    int row = 0, col = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numCams; i++)
    {
        labels[i] = new QLabel;

        row = i / numCols;
        col = i % numCols;
        grid->addWidget(labels[i], row, col);


        threads[i] = new QThread;
        workers[i] = new Worker(QString("/home/shang/Videos/%1.mp4").arg(i+1), i);
        workers[i]->moveToThread(threads[i]);

        connect(workers[i], SIGNAL(frameFinished(cv::Mat, int)), this, SLOT(displayFrame(cv::Mat,int)));
        connect(threads[i], SIGNAL(started()), workers[i], SLOT(readVideo()));

        connect(workers[i], SIGNAL(finished(int)), threads[i], SLOT(quit()));
        connect(workers[i], SIGNAL(finished(int)), workers[i], SLOT(deleteLater()));

        connect(threads[i], SIGNAL(finished()), threads[i], SLOT(deleteLater()));

        threads[i]->start();
    }

    this->centralWidget()->setLayout(grid);

}

void MainWindow::file_open_clicked(){
       QString Path = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName( this,tr("OpenVideo"),"","Video (*.avi)");
    if(Path.isEmpty())
        return;
     view =3; 
    connect(this, SIGNAL(send_to_worker(QString)),workers[view], SLOT(get_from_main(QString)));
    emit this->send_to_worker(recorder_Path);
}

void MainWindow::displayFrame(cv::Mat frame, int index)
{
    QPixmap p = QPixmap::fromImage(QImage(frame.data, frame.cols, frame.rows, frame.step, QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped());
    p = p.scaled(QSize(frame.cols/2, frame.rows/2));
    labels[index]->setPixmap(p);
}
```

[Qt + OpenCV play videos with std::thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29338250/qt-opencv-play-videos-with-stdthread)

Comment: Your implementation of `Worker::readVideo` has an infinite loop -- `while (true) { ... }` -- that never processes any `Qt` events -- so queued signals will never be delivered.

Comment: @G.M., thanks for pointing out problem. I am trying to find solution to it. And learnt of QMutex. But, all example here share variables between two thread class. Can you please share any example which shares variable between mainwindow and worker thread class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to perform an operation periodically whilst still processing events -- that's simply calling out for a [`QTimer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html).

(Note that the following code is untested.)

Change your `Worker` class to make use of a `QTimer` rather than a loop that blocks the event queue...

```
class Worker: public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT;
public:
  Worker (QString path, int id);
  ~Worker();
public slots:
  void readVideo(QString path = "");
  void get_from_main(QString path);
signals:
  // frame and index of label which frame will be displayed
  void frameFinished(cv::Mat frame, int index);
  void finished(int index);
private:
  QString          filepath;
  int              index;
  QTimer           timer;
  cv::VideoCapture cap;
};

Worker::Worker (QString path, int id)
  : filepath(path)
  , index(id)
  , timer(this)
  , cap(filepath.toStdString())
{

  /*
   * Connect QTimer::timeout to the readVideo slot that will read a
   * single frame on each signal at 30ms intervals.
   */
  connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &Worker::readVideo);
  timer.start(30);
}

Worker::~Worker ()
{
}

void Worker::get_from_main (QString path)
{
  qDebug() << "updating";
  filepath = path;
  cap = cv::VideoCapture(filepath);
  if (!cap.isOpened()) {
    qDebug() << "Can't open video file " << filepath;
    emit finished(index);
  }
}

void Worker::readVideo ()
{
  cv::Mat frame;
  cap >> frame;
  if (frame.empty())
  {
    frame = cv::Mat(cv::Size(720, 576), CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(192, 0, 0));
    emit frameFinished(frame, index);
    break;
  }

  emit frameFinished(frame.clone(), index);
}
```

Now `Worker::readVideo` simply reads a single frame from the capture and then returns to the event loop.

Also remove the line...

```
connect(threads[i], SIGNAL(started()), workers[i], SLOT(readVideo()));
```

from `MainWindow::init`.  As I stated above this is untested and probably needs a *lot* more error checking.  But it should give you a good idea as to what's required.